# Cant change the color of a TPanel in delphi

Tags: delphi

the color of my panel wont change with this code. I tried it with a button as well. I'm fairly new to Delphi so any answers would be appreciated. Thanks

```
procedure TForm1.pnlClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  pnl.Color := clYellow;
end;
```

Comment: See [Delphi 2009 - create a TPanel at runtime and change its color](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3778161/576719).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try set values like `ParentBackground` and `ParentColor` to false.